# Excel misaligns columns when appending dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a program that takes a `URL` as input, and checks it against a `df` that I'm reading from csv:

```
   Name   ID      Date                    URL
0  Faye  111  12/31/16   https://www.url1.com
1  Faye  111   3/31/17   https://www.url2.com
2  Mike  222   3/31/17   https://www.url3.com
3  Mike  222   6/30/18   https://www.url4.com
4  Mike  222   9/30/18   https://www.url5.com
5   Jim  333   9/30/18   https://www.url6.com
```

If the `URL` doesn't exist in the `df`, the program executes some code, and then adds a new row with the `URL` to the `df`; else it moves on to another `URL`.

The program works fine if I just run it, stop it, and restart it. But if I *delete* an existing row (e.g., `[1]`) directly from the csv file in Excel to reprocess the data for that one url, it gets added at column `[4]` and row `[5]` to `df`:

```
   Name   ID      Date                    URL
0  Faye  111  12/31/16   https://www.url1.com
2  Mike  222   3/31/17   https://www.url3.com
3  Mike  222   6/30/18   https://www.url4.com
4  Mike  222   9/30/18   https://www.url5.com
5   Jim  333   9/30/18   https://www.url6.com    Faye  111   3/31/17   https://www.url2.com
```

rather than adding at row `[6]` as a new row, which happens when I remove the row in a plain text editor (rather than Excel):

```
   Name   ID      Date                     URL
    ...  ...       ...                     ...
5   Jim  333   9/30/18    https://www.url6.com
6  Faye  111   3/31/17    https://www.url2.com
```

I'm adding the data to the existing csv via `df.to_csv('~/file.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)`, so can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please provide your code in the question

Comment: This could be due to a difference in opinion of what a line ending is using your various tools. Look at the last few lines in your example (`print(open("test.csv", "rb").read()[-200:])`) and see. If there is no `\n` at the end or an odd mixture of `\n` and `\r\n`, there's your problem.

Comment: How could I go about fixing that though?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying appending *another* (1-line) dataframe as *another* chunk of CSV-file:

```
df.to_csv('~/file.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

append it first to your dataframe

```
df = df.append(your_1_row_df, ignore_index=True)
```

and only then write it into your `~/file.csv`, this time with the (default) mode `'w'` (effectively rewriting it):

```
df.to_csv('~/file.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: But if I rewrite it, don't I overwrite the existing rows?

Comment: Yes, you overwrite your file completely, but all existing rows are *saved in your `df`*, so they will be written again. You may first make copy of your original file (e. g. `cp ~/file.csv ~/file_copy.csv`) if you are afraid of losing it.

Comment: Hmm I'd still prefer to add, rather than replace as eventually this going to be writing/reading from a database.

Comment: I wish you joy.

Comment: I think this might be an Excel issue because when I delete the row from the csv file in a plain text editor, the program works fine...

Comment: Where in your question is mentioned Excel?

Comment: It didn't but that's because I didn't realize it was the culprit

Comment: Interesting enough. You didn't know the culprit, but you (in your original answer) supposed that Excel is not.